# sharepoint online - auto re-assign "created by", following validation error from people picker

Tags: sharepoint-online

In SharePoint online, when a person entered as "created by" is no longer in active directory old entries when opened for editing cannot be re-saved due to validation error.  Is it possible to re-populate this field automatically with an alternative name on open form?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell script to update Created by, Modified By, Created at, Modified at field values:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

##Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/sales/"
$ListName= "Projects"
$ID=6
$UserID="Salaudeen@crescent.com"
$TimeStamp = "2015/12/01 02:10:00 AM"

#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

#Setup the context
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

#Get the User
$User = $Ctx.Web.EnsureUser($UserID)
$ctx.Load($user)

#Get the list Item
$List=$Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
$ListItem = $List.GetItemById($ID)
$Ctx.Load($ListItem)

#Update Created by & Modified By
$ListItem["Author"] = $User
$ListItem['Editor'] = $User

#Set Created on & Modified on Time values
$ListItem["Created"] =  $TimeStamp
$ListItem["Modified"] = $TimeStamp

#Update List item
$ListItem.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

Write-host "Metadata values updated Successfully!" -f Green
```

More information:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/11/update-created-by-modified-by-created-at-modified-at-values-using-powershell.html